# Taxes on capital gains and dividends for non-resident alien

Tags: united-states, dividends, non-resident, capital-gain, spain

I am a citizen of Spain living in Spain. In the past I lived in the US for over 10 yrs. During the time I lived in the US I opened a brokerage account to trade stocks.

Now I have two options:

1. Claim the Spain-US tax treaty and pay taxes on dividends and capital gains in Spain which are very high or
2. Be a non-resident alien US Tax payer and pay US taxes on capital gains and dividends.

My question is: What are the tax rates for non-resident alien on dividends and capital gains ?

Thanks for your help

Arturo

Comment: What makes you think that in the case #2 you won't be liable for taxes in Spain?